# displayfield and textfield change

Tags: extjs4.1

I have created a window which has a grid and a form that displays values in plain displayfields of the records in the grid when clicked on.

There is an "New" button for the form and once clicked by the user, the displayfields should switch to textfields which should allow you to enter a new record into a database.

Can anybody point me towards a certain direction in order to do this? I am a complete newbie to ExtJS and only just started learning ExtJS4.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the row editing plugin.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing

You will need to add that to the plugins config item on the grid, then add editor configs to each of the columns that you want to edit.  The editor config is generally just a xtype and config options for one of the components found in Ext.form.field.*.